# issue with OnvideoClicklistener goes to YouTube main page

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-video-player, android-youtube-api

I have looked at the SO but I found one similar question but it didn't help me.

I have built my first Android application my application should play videos from my YouTube channel with a dynamic list of videos 
I run the application in my Android emulator but when I click on the video thumbnail in my application it goes to YouTube main page

I don't know is it something with the emulator target.

I followed and online tutorial on this one.

this is the `Main.java` for the video:

```
/**
* The Activity can retrieve Videos for a specific username from YouTube</br>
* It then displays them into a list including the Thumbnail preview and the title</br>
* There is a reference to each video on YouTube as well but this isn't used in this tutorial</br>
* </br>
* <b>Note<b/> orientation change isn't covered in this tutorial, you will want to override
* onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() when you come to this
* </br>
* @author paul.blundell
*/
public class maincontentview extends Activity implements VideoClickListener {
// A reference to our list that will hold the video details
private VideosListView listView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.maincontentview);

listView = (VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView);
listView.setOnVideoClickListener(this);
}

// This is the XML onClick listener to retreive a users video feed
public void getUserYouTubeFeed(View v){
// We start a new task that does its work on its own thread
// We pass in a handler that will be called when the task has finished
// We also pass in the name of the user we are searching YouTube for
new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, "projectofdawah").run();
}

// This is the handler that receives the response when the YouTube task has finished
Handler responseHandler = new Handler() {
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
populateListWithVideos(msg);
};
};

/**
* This method retrieves the Library of videos from the task and passes them to our ListView
* @param msg
*/
private void populateListWithVideos(Message msg) {
// Retreive the videos are task found from the data bundle sent back
Library lib = (Library) msg.getData().get(GetYouTubeUserVideosTask.LIBRARY);
// Because we have created a custom ListView we don't have to worry about setting the adapter in the activity
// we can just call our custom method with the list of items we want to display
listView.setVideos(lib.getVideos());
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
// Make sure we null our handler when the activity has stopped
// because who cares if we get a callback once the activity has stopped? not me!
responseHandler = null;
super.onStop();
}

// This is the interface method that is called when a video in the listview is clicked!
// The interface is a contract between this activity and the listview
@Override
public void onVideoClicked(com.mohammed.watzIslam.Video video) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(video.getUrl()));
startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

this is the video java file

```
    package com.mohammed.watzIslam;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.provider.MediaStore.Video;
    import android.view.View;







    /**
    * The Activity can retrieve Videos for a specific username from YouTube</br>
    * It then displays them into a list including the Thumbnail preview and the title</br>
    * There is a reference to each video on YouTube as well but this isn't used in this tutorial</br>
    * </br>
    * <b>Note<b/> orientation change isn't covered in this tutorial, you will want to override
    * onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() when you come to this
    * </br>
    */
    public class maincontentview extends Activity implements VideoClickListener {
    // A reference to our list that will hold the video details
    private VideosListView listView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maincontentview);

    listView = (VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView);
    listView.setOnVideoClickListener(this);
    }

    // This is the XML onClick listener to retreive a users video feed
    public void getUserYouTubeFeed(View v){
    // We start a new task that does its work on its own thread
    // We pass in a handler that will be called when the task has finished
    // We also pass in the name of the user we are searching YouTube for
    new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, "projectofdawah").run();
    }

    // This is the handler that receives the response when the YouTube task has finished
    Handler responseHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    populateListWithVideos(msg);
    };
    };

    /**
    * This method retrieves the Library of videos from the task and passes them to our ListView
    * @param msg
    */
    private void populateListWithVideos(Message msg) {
    // Retreive the videos are task found from the data bundle sent back
    Library lib = (Library) msg.getData().get(GetYouTubeUserVideosTask.LIBRARY);
    // Because we have created a custom ListView we don't have to worry about setting the adapter in the activity
    // we can just call our custom method with the list of items we want to display
    listView.setVideos(lib.getVideos());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
    // Make sure we null our handler when the activity has stopped
    // because who cares if we get a callback once the activity has stopped? not me!
    responseHandler = null;
    super.onStop();
    }

    // This is the interface method that is called when a video in the listview is clicked!
    // The interface is a contract between this activity and the listview
    @Override
    public void onVideoClicked(com.mohammed.watzIslam.Video video) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(video.getUrl()));
    startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
```

and this one the video listview.java

```
package com.mohammed.watzIslam;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;




    public class VideosListView extends ListView implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener  {

private List<Video> videos;
private VideoClickListener videoClickListener;

public VideosListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public VideosListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
}

public VideosListView(Context context) {
super(context);
}

public void setVideos(List<Video> videos){
this.videos = videos;
VideosAdapter adapter = new VideosAdapter(getContext(), videos);
setAdapter(adapter);
// When the videos are set we also set an item click listener to the list
// this will callback to our custom list whenever an item it pressed
// it will tell us what position in the list is pressed
setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

// Calling this method sets a listener to the list
// Whatever class is passed in will be notified when the list is pressed
// (The class that is passed in just has to 'implement VideoClickListener'
// meaning is has the methods available we want to call)
public void setOnVideoClickListener(VideoClickListener l) {
videoClickListener = l;}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
super.setAdapter(adapter);
}

// When we receive a notification that a list item was pressed
// we check to see if a video listener has been set
// if it has we can then tell the listener 'hey a video has just been clicked' also passing the video
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
if(videoClickListener != null){
    videoClickListener.onVideoClicked(videos.get(position));
}
}

}
```

logcat

```
    05-09 09:10:58.080: I/Choreographer(914): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:11:33.139: E/Trace(968): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 09:11:34.219: D/dalvikvm(968): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 48K, 3% free 8014K/8259K, paused 81ms, total 83ms
05-09 09:11:34.269: I/dalvikvm-heap(968): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.977MB for 1156016-byte allocation
05-09 09:11:34.459: D/dalvikvm(968): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 9142K/9415K, paused 82ms+30ms, total 186ms
05-09 09:11:35.400: D/gralloc_goldfish(968): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-09 09:11:38.101: D/dalvikvm(968): GC_CONCURRENT freed 19K, 2% free 9572K/9735K, paused 94ms+109ms, total 311ms
05-09 09:11:38.740: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 141 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:11:39.490: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 98 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:11:41.310: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:11:42.190: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:11:51.540: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:11:51.850: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:11:58.519: D/Button(968): Login
05-09 09:11:59.860: E/JSON(968): {"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"id":"518a7c7904eda1.69983308","user":{"name":"a","email":"a","created_at":"2013-05-09 00:25:29","updated_at":null}}
05-09 09:12:02.620: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:12:10.931: D/dalvikvm(968): GC_CONCURRENT freed 197K, 3% free 9837K/10119K, paused 74ms+91ms, total 273ms
05-09 09:12:15.679: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:12:17.450: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:12:17.651: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:12:22.071: I/System.out(968): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBiyaXMVM90&feature=youtube_gdata_player
05-09 09:12:22.071: I/System.out(968): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBiyaXMVM90&feature=youtube_gdata_player
05-09 09:12:22.630: D/dalvikvm(968): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1603K, 17% free 8807K/10503K, paused 87ms+83ms, total 259ms
05-09 09:12:22.630: D/dalvikvm(968): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
05-09 09:12:23.470: I/System.out(968): URL :- hBiyaXMVM90
05-09 09:12:23.590: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 339 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:12:24.561: D/MediaPlayer(968): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-09 09:12:24.931: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 304 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:12:25.450: D/MediaPlayer(968): getMetadata
05-09 09:12:25.591: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:12:31.744: E/MediaPlayer(968): error (1, -2147483648)
05-09 09:12:31.744: E/MediaPlayer(968): Error (1,-2147483648)
05-09 09:12:31.750: D/VideoView(968): Error: 1,-2147483648
05-09 09:12:32.140: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-09 09:12:33.560: I/Choreographer(968): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

hope to have help from you guys

Comment: is there nobody who knows something about this!!!!

Comment: Can you give more information about what is actually happening and what you are trying to do? I presume this: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/click-item-in-a-listview-to-show-youtube-video/ is the tutorial you are attempting to follow

Comment: @o0rebelious0o well it's like the tutorial I have a list of videos from my YouTube channel but when I click on any of the videos' thumbnail it takes me YouTube main page it's not even the video page on YouTube!!!.I need it to play the video in my application,and I guess the tutorial presumes the same.yup it's the same tutorial I follow..if you need any other part of the code do let me know dude.

Comment: Before you start the activity, Log the video.getURL() to check it is definitely a valid youtube URL. Which video player are you trying to play the video with?  This is the format for launching a youtube video: startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxx")));  Check your video URL is in that format

Comment: @o0rebelious0o I added my main.java into the question to make it clearer.to log you mean I place a catch before onvideoclicked in my main?? the player I really don't know I followed the tutorial sorry dude I'm some how new.

Comment: Change: public void onVideoClicked(com.mohammed.watzIslam.Video video) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(video.getUrl()));
    startActivity(intent);
    } TO: public void onVideoClicked(com.mohammed.watzIslam.Video video) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(video.getUrl()));
    Log.i("YOUTUBE URL", ""+video.getUrl());
    startActivity(intent);
    } and post the logcat result in the question

Comment: @o0rebelious0o I have done the changes and post the logcat. before I run it I had and error at the log.i as I have a log.java where there exists a log.i method but seems here the parametrs are not the same so I did some changes to get rid of the error and I ran it

Comment: @o0rebelious0o  are you still here....can somebody carry on with this case?

Comment: @user2309720 Did you solve it or not ?

Comment: @Hardik I will try your answer and get back to you

Comment: @Hardik I replied to your answer dude

Answer (score 1):

You need to split video id from url and pass it to next activity like following.

```
@Override
    public void onVideoClicked(Video video) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(video.getUrl());
        Intent videointent = new Intent(DisplayVideo.this,
                YouTubeVideo.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        System.out.println(video.getUrl());

        bundle.putString("videoid", video.getUrl().split("v=")[1].split("&")[0]);
        videointent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(videointent);
    }
```

Now `YouTubeVideo.java` looks like following.

```
public class YouTubeVideo extends Activity {
    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle instance) {
        super.onCreate(instance);
        setContentView(R.layout.playvideo);
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String data = bundle.getString("videoid");
        final VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        mc.setEnabled(true);
        mc.show(0);
        vv.setMediaController(mc);
        vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(getUrlVideoRTSP(data)));
        vv.requestFocus();
        vv.showContextMenu();
        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                vv.start();

            }
        });

        vv.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                return false;
            }
        });
        System.out.println("URL :- " + data);
    }
    public static String getUrlVideoRTSP(String urlYoutube) {
        try {
            String gdy = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/YOURUSERNAME/uploads/";
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            String id = extractYoutubeId(urlYoutube);
            URL url = new URL(gdy + id);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
            Element el = doc.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList list = el.getElementsByTagName("media:content");// /media:content
            String cursor = urlYoutube;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = list.item(i);
                if (node != null) {
                    NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
                    HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < nodeMap.getLength(); j++) {
                        Attr att = (Attr) nodeMap.item(j);
                        maps.put(att.getName(), att.getValue());
                    }
                    if (maps.containsKey("yt:format")) {
                        String f = maps.get("yt:format");
                        if (maps.containsKey("url")) {
                            cursor = maps.get("url");
                        }
                        if (f.equals("1"))
                            return cursor;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cursor;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Get Url Video RTSP Exception======>>", ex.toString());
        }
        return urlYoutube;
    }
    private static String extractYoutubeId(String url) {
        return url;
    }

}
```

`getUrlVideoRTSP()` convert your URL into `rtsp` format which play in `videoview`.

Now I also add xml file for `playvideo`

**playvideo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlinear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/VideoView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thats it. Now your video play in videoview inside your application.

> I don't know is it something with the emulator target.

No. It will play in Emulator also but it takes more time to play. So its batter to test in real device.

Thanks.
Happy Codding.

Comment: I guess you know the tutorial I'm following,there is a GetYouTubeUSerVideoTask.java I assume your YouTubeVideo.java should replace that one?

Comment: but I'm getting error with DisplyVideo.java (can't be resolved as a type) either create a class,interface,or change to displya(android.view) and some other suggestion also the geturl() says undefined

Comment: This code not working ???  I don't mean that but I mean how it's integrated with my currents codes any replacement or just add it ?

Comment: You need to just integrate this code its working in my case. I am using same example(Blundell).

Comment: what about the errors what suggestion should I choose to get rid of them

Comment: After integrate my code what errors are you getting ? Paste it.

Comment: with Displayvideo I got this one:                          DisplayVideo cannot be resolved to a type                                        with geturl I receive this one:                                   The method getUrl() is undefined for the type MediaStore.Video                    with log.e at YouTubeVideo.java I got this                            The method e(String, Throwable) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Comment: oaky..okay dude I fixed the geturl error now the onclick looks like this    public void onVideoClicked(com.mohammed.watzIslam.Video video)   because the same method at the videoclicklistner.java has this parameter so I match them

Comment: what do you suggest for the log.e coz in my log.java there exists a similier e method but the parameters don't match I guess                        the DisplayVideo.this I changed it into maincontentview.this that's the name of the java file where this method reside I hope I done it correctly?

Comment: I tired to fix the errors dude...but now when I click on the video from the list it says can't play this video... I can't test in my real device because there's a user reg. and login with mysql hosted in my pc and I found that my phone and I guess most Android phones don't support the adhoc.

Comment: Print(in Log) what is there in "data" while you set  vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(getUrlVideoRTSP(data)));

Comment: do you mean I run the app. and print you the logcat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29655/discussion-between-hardik-and-user2309720)